# Wordpress sites translate dynamically generated Homepages

Tags: templates, language

So I'm having trouble finding a way to translate the homepage content on a few pages I manage.

They can be found here:

1. [KorgCanada.com](http://www.korgcanada.com) (Theme is Simplecorp, and the support forum offers no help)
2. [EriksonMusic.com](http://www.eriksonmusic.com) (Theme is target, and again, absolutely no help)

I'm using the **Poplarware Language Switcher** plugin which is an outdated/ no longer maintained plugin for translating pages/ posts etc. It functions by using tags like `[lang_en]` English goes here `[/lang_en][lang_fr]` French here `[/lang_fr]`.

And it's working perfectly for all my pages/ posts, EXCEPT for the dynamically generated homepages of both the sites, which is made up of the "Theme options" tabs within the GUI. If I put those tags in the text areas for those, they show up as plain text, and don't actually translate anything.

I was hoping somebody could help me regulate this, preferably while using the same plugin, and perhaps just making a page template of the homepage, and hard-coding the French version myself... but I'm totally uncertain about how to go about this.
If you have any ideas how I can accomplish this, please lend me a hand, I'm getting very desperate.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you have installed hooks into the_content() function which is called within the post loop on your posts - this is why it works there and not the text only widgets. You may find a PHP widget will work OR you can use PHP to run your shortcode using the do_shortcode function.

PHP widget plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/

Shortcode example:

`<? echo do_shortcode('[lang_en] English goes here [/lang_en]'); ?>`

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, this sounds intriguing indeed....

Can you give me more concise info on how to accomplish this ? Would the aforementioned shortcode let me be able to input text directly into the same GUI's textbox, but I'll be able to put the english AND french txt there ?

Looking forward to hearing back from you,

Comment: Hey Innate, so after some hacking & slashing around, I've come to realize that my best option is probably just to make a custom homepage template, which has both the english and french content on it, within the [lang] tags, like your 2nd suggestion mentions. 

However, I tried to implement the code: <? echo do_shortcode('[lang_en] English goes here [/lang_en]'); ?> into my page template, but it still shows up as [lang_en], and doesn't function as expected...

Any further instruction on this type of configuration would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance, hope you can help me out :)